# Date join and rank within a time period

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to make a rank and join within a period of 10 days using either Scala Spark or SQL.

I have a table that contains Tries of users and another one that has Contracts. They have id's on which I can join them but on top of that id I need to consider a certain time frame. To simplify the example let's say all my entries have the same id:

```
Tries:
try, try_day
Try 1, 2018-08-01 
 Try 2, 2018-09-01
Try 3, 2018-10-01
Try 4, 2018-10-02

Contracts:
contract, contract_day
Contract 1, 2018-08-01
Contract 2, 2018-09-02
Contract 3, 2018-10-01
```

I only want to join these if 1) There is a difference of more than 10 days between the tries and 2) there is maximum 2 days diference between the dates of the two tables. So in the end I get:

```
try, try_day, contract, contract_day, (explanation)

Try 1, 2018-08-01, Contract 1, 2018-08-01 , (same date and more than 10 days between try 1 and try 2)
 Try 2, 2018-09-01, Contract 2, 2018-09-02, (difference of less than 2 days, and more than 10 days between try 2 and try 3)
Try 3, 2018-10-01, null, null (there is less than 10 days difference between try 3 and try 4 so contract should match with try 4 only)
Try 4, 2018-10-02, Contract 3, 2018-10-01
```

I thought I might want to rank the dates for the tries and then do a join only on the once that rank first. But then I need to rank only in a 10-days window.

```
SELECT *, dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY try_day DESC) as rank
FROM tries
```

Unfortunately, this will rank all of them from 1 till 4 but I want to get a rank of

```
try, try_day, rank
Try 1, 2018-08-01, 1 
 Try 2, 2018-09-01, 1
Try 3, 2018-10-01, 2
Try 4, 2018-10-02, 1
```

and then make my join on where the rank is 1 and data is within 2 days.

IF someone has a better logical idea on how to achieve that it's also welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach using `unix_timestamp` and Window function `lead` to calculate `rank` based on the condition re: `try_day`s between consecutive rows, and `left-join`-ing the two DataFrames on the condition re: `try_day` and `contract_day`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import spark.implicits._

val dfTries = Seq(
  ("Try 1", "2018-08-01"),
  ("Try 2", "2018-09-01"),
  ("Try 3", "2018-10-01"),
  ("Try 4", "2018-10-02")
).toDF("try", "try_day")

val dfContracts = Seq(
  ("contract 1", "2018-08-01"),
  ("contract 2", "2018-09-02"),
  ("contract 3", "2018-10-01"),
).toDF("contract", "contract_day")

dfTries.
  withColumn("try_ts", unix_timestamp($"try_day", "yyyy-MM-dd")).
  withColumn("prev_try_ts", lead($"try_ts", 1).over(Window.orderBy($"try"))).
  withColumn("rank", when(
      $"prev_try_ts".isNull || abs($"try_ts" - $"prev_try_ts") > 10 * 24 * 3600,
      1
    ).otherwise(2)
  ).
  join(
    dfContracts,
    $"rank" === 1 && abs($"try_ts" - unix_timestamp($"contract_day", "yyyy-MM-dd")) <= 2 * 24 * 3600,
    "left_outer").
  show
// +-----+----------+----------+-----------+----+----------+------------+
// |  try|   try_day|    try_ts|prev_try_ts|rank|  contract|contract_day|
// +-----+----------+----------+-----------+----+----------+------------+
// |Try 1|2018-08-01|1533106800| 1535785200|   1|contract 1|  2018-08-01|
// |Try 2|2018-09-01|1535785200| 1538377200|   1|contract 2|  2018-09-02|
// |Try 3|2018-10-01|1538377200| 1538463600|   2|      null|        null|
// |Try 4|2018-10-02|1538463600|       null|   1|contract 3|  2018-10-01|
// +-----+----------+----------+-----------+----+----------+------------+
```

It's worth noting that using Window function without `partitionBy` would not scale well.